# need syntax for conditional logic for Properties keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I need help to figure out the syntax of a Cloudformation section that deals with creating a Default Route for a Private Subnet Route Table.  The logic of the template is such that the stack creator chooses dev or prod at launch. If prod is chosen, 2 NAT Gateways are created, one in each AZ.  If dev is chosen, a single NAT instance is created. In the Resources definition for the Default Private Routes, I need to be able to choose between using InstanceID: and GatewayID: depending on which is chosen.

What I've tried that doesn't work:

```
  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      !If
      - IsProd
      -
        GatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1
        RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      - InstanceId: !Ref NATInstance
        RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
        DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Tests:
prod: hangs on DefaultPrivateRoute1 'Resource creation initiated', then fails with "Route did not stabilize in expected time"

dev: works!

```
 DefaultPrivateRoute1:
   Type: AWS::EC2::Route
   Properties:
     !If
     - IsProd
     -
       GatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1
     - InstanceId: !Ref NATInstance
       RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
       DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Tests:
prod: Fails on DefaultPrivateRoute1 with 'Exactly one of DestinationCidrBlock and DestinationIpv6CidrBlock must be specified and not empty'

dev: works!

```
  DefaultPrivateRoute1:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Route
    Properties:
      RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
      DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
      !If
      - IsProd
      -
        GatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1
      - InstanceId: !Ref NATInstance
```

Tests:
prod: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 200, column 7) (1st line after the !If statement)

dev: Template format error: YAML not well-formed. (line 200, column 7) (1st line after the !If statement)

Does anyone have an ideas how this should be formatted?

Answer (score 0):

The correct property is NatGatewayId, not GatewayId.

```
Type: AWS::EC2::Route
Properties:
  !If
  - IsProd
  - NatGatewayId: !Ref NatGateway1
    RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
    DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
  - InstanceId: !Ref NATInstanceBastion
    RouteTableId: !Ref PrivateRouteTable1
    DestinationCidrBlock: 0.0.0.0/0
```